# Synchronize column in RowDetailsTemplate with a column in the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I wonder if it is possible to accomplish this with `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`?

[image: Example]

I want that when the user select a row in the `DataGrid`, details about the row appear under the row. So far I know how to do.
The problem is that I want the time column in the `RowDetailsTemplate` be synchronized with the corresponding column in the `DataGrid`?

Comment: Not sure if I understood that 100%.

Comment: I do not blame you. I'm not very good at English.
I want that when the user clicks on a row, more details about the row appears below the line. So far I know how to do. The problem is that I want that the sub table that appears to have a column that is as wide as in the main table.

Comment: Got your point. Check the Ans. And Do accept if you like :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <ItemContainerTemplate>                      
        <DockPanel >
           <Rectangle Name="LeftRect" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Width="{Binding ElementName=DG1, Path=Columns[0].ActualWidth}" Height="40" Fill="Red"></Rectangle>
           <Rectangle Name="RightRect" Height="40" Fill="Yellow"></Rectangle>
        </DockPanel>
    </ItemContainerTemplate>                
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Here I have used a DockPanel with 2 `Rectangle` as Item container for simplicity you can you Grid/Panels.
The trick is to Bind the `Width` of the LeftRect to the `Width` of the `DataGrid`'s first column and mark it `Dock=Left`. Since, this is `DockPanel` rest of the space will be filled by RightRect.

You can use `RelativeSource` or `ElemenatName` to do it. Here I have used `ElementName`, where DG1 is the name of my `DataGrid` control.

Also make sure you have `RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"` set on the DataGrid.

Comment: Thank you :-)
But how can I make my first column in the sub table has the same width as the column in the main table?

Comment: Use a Grid instead and Bind the Width of Column 1 with that of DataGrid and Width of the column 2 with rest of the DataGrid. To calculate the width of the rest of the DataGrid, I would assume you can use a Converter to do the math.

Comment: There is one more way. Could you try Freezing the first column? I am not sure of it's effect on RowDetailsTemplate. ref:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.frozencolumncount%28VS.95%29.aspx